# JSfiddle not 'defining' function?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/naqaz3mc/2/

I have been having a lot of problems with JSfiddle. I am new to it so I may be doing something wrong. 
When I click the `clickMe` button, I recieve this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickMe is not defined`. The code works when I copy it directly into a local file.

---

P.S. I don't know if it makes a difference but I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

[Check the options in the side](http://jsfiddle.net/naqaz3mc/3/). You need to have `no-wrap <head>` which makes sure the functions are placed properly in the code.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Can you take a screenshot? Your link just goes back to his fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the options in the side please. It's not the same fiddle.